# What does “all policies and procedures apply” mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I received an email from my travel agency. I got the general message but there was a sentence that tripped me up.

> Unfortunately the airline has denied our request for refund, please be
> advised all current airline policies and procedures including all fees
> apply.

What does this mean? Especially the part after please be advised. Apply to what? There was no context to understand other than my refund request being denied.

Comment: That "please be advised" bit is just reminding you that all relevant "airline policies and procedures" are still the same as they ever were (they haven't been suspended because of Covid, or whatever).

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd understand that sentence.

First half: The airline has said no to the the request for refund the travel agency made.

Second half: Please know that all the policies and procedures that the airline has, including any fees are still applicable and will likely be applied.

"all ... including all fees apply" means that all fees are still going to be charged.

They are not explaining which fees are going to apply nor any reason about the denial on that phrase.